# highchart - pointstart with given x values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart that is displaying a time series data, the problem I am having is that each series is beginning at Jan 1 unless I define a pointStart. As documented here [HighCharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart), my understanding is that you can specify pointStart if no x values are given for points in the series.

However, what I am trying to accomplish is to get each series plotted at the first x value that is given dynamically without hard-coding a date.

For example this is my data,

```
  var dataArray = [{
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
  Brand: "Toyota",
  Count: 3
 }, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-02",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 258
 }, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 239
 }, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 197
 }, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-05",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 187
 }, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-06",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 418
 }, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 344
 }, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
  Brand: "Mercedes",
  Count: 43
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
  Brand: "Mercedes",
  Count: 220
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
  Brand: "Chrysler",
  Count: 3
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
  Brand: "Chrysler",
  Count: 3
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-06",
 Brand: "Chrysler",
 Count: 6
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
 Brand: "Chrysler",
 Count: 1
}];
```

I'd like each brand to be plotted at it's first x value, etc. Rather than plotted at a hard coded pointStart.

Here is my jsfiddle: 
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1a4kt5u/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `point.ErrorDate` with `new Date(point.ErrorDate).getTime()` it converts date  to microsecond as required by highcharts

```
var seriesArr = [];
dataArray.forEach(function(point) {

  var newPoint = [new Date(point.ErrorDate).getTime(), point.Count],
    seriesIndex = seriesArr.findIndex((series) => series.name === point.Brand);

  if (seriesIndex === -1) {
    seriesArr.push({
      name: point.Brand,
      data: [newPoint]
    });
  } else {
    seriesArr[seriesIndex].data.push(newPoint);
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/q73nknrf/) demo